# How do I fix a broken window in my aluminum framed sunroom?

Tags: repair, windows

A lower window is broken in my aluminum framed sunroom, as shown in this 33 second video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLQfd0FPwYU

Will I need to:

1. drill out rivets
2. take apart the whole section of wall
3. cut a custom size of glass, etc?

Or do the windows come pre-framed in standardized sizes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Video is no longer private. It was supposed to be just "unlisted".

Comment: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/8716/gde.jpg
http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/9689/qb9l.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace just the sheet of glass, which can be obtained cheap/easy/quickly at nearly any hardware store or similar.  The store will cut a piece to your measurements.

Taking care to not damage anything else, I'd remove the outside bevel, cutting/ripping it out, destroying the bevel if necessary.  By bevel, I mean the triangular piece that normally presses up against the glass.  It looks to be about 1/2 wide. This would not involve drilling out any rivets or using a rivet gun.

I'd then insert a new window pane, then either reinstall the old/new bevel, or just caulk it place with a silicone caulk.

The important thing is to not damage anything else.

For measurements, you can cut a piece of cardboard to size and test it out in the opening. Bring it in to the store to show the employee and to compare it to the piece that they cut, just to double check that it is the right size.

Comment: But the new frame and glass would need to be custom cut to a non-standard size? That's the main worry.

Comment: No new frame, just new glass.  The new glass is quick/easy/cheap to get at nearly any glass shop, or hardware store or similar.  The store will cut a piece of glass to size for you. The new glass will seat against the inside lip.

Comment: the important thing is to not damage anything else while removing the outside bevel.

Comment: OK thanks. As long as the store will make it fit snug in the frame so I don't have to worry about that part of it. Guess I need a rivet gun too.

Comment: If your think you will need a rivet gun, then we are not on the same page, so to say.  As far as the fit, see my modified answer about using a piece of cardboard.